# incompatible types in Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter4j, incompatibletypeerror

I'm following this tutorial for twitter4j:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/10/java-twitter-client-with-twitter4j.html

and I've gotten almost everything right. All my code compiles except for this one little part:

```java
 ResponseList list = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
    for (Status each : list) { //incompatible types error

        System.out.println("Sent by: @" + each.getUser().getScreenName()
                + " - " + each.getUser().getName() + "\n" + each.getText()
                + "\n");
    }
```

This is the output for that exception:
incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: twitter4j.Status

I'm using the twitter4j 2.2.5 jars.
What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics is missing, maybe you could try:

```
    ResponseList<Status> list = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
    for (Status each : list) {

        System.out.println("Sent by: @" + each.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + each.getUser().getName() + "\n"
                + each.getText() + "\n");
    }
```